# Static Table Cells in NIB File

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, interface-builder

Is it possible to create a nib file that has a table view with custom static cells? I want to create a form-like table view with all static content, but I'm not currently using storyboards. I was able to find the content type menu in the default Storyboard of my app, but I'm using Nibs, and when I create either a UIViewController nib or a UITableViewController nib, in both cases there is no content type menu in the Attributes inspector tab.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like at the moment, what I'm trying to do is just not supported. I filed a Radar bug on Apple, but here's the workaround that worked for me.

Just use a storyboard, and call it like a nib using:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"EditProfile" bundle:nil];
EditProfileTVC *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EditProfile"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Where in your storyboard, you name the view controller you want to start on as EditProfile, in this case. Hope this helps someone out.

Comment: Best approach till now..!! using the same method in '17

Answer (score 0):

There's a process to this, but it's not overly complicated:

- Create a new Cocoatouch class by pressing Command + N and selecting it under the iOS > Source menu.
- Name your class, make it a subclass of ViewController and finally check the 'Also create XIB file' box.
- Open your XIB file and define the Custom Class under the identity inspector to point to the name of YourNewViewController

Sample of this at work:
In .h :

```
@interface LocationsListViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) myMapManager* mapManager;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView* tableView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSMutableArray* locations;


@end
```

Then, in .m:

```
#import "LocationsListViewController.h"
#import "CustomCellController.h"
#import "myMapAnnotation.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

//Define MKMap details, easier to change later

#define kCellHeight 70
#define kMainCellIdentifier @"mainCellIdentifier"
#define kMainCellNib @"CustomCell"
#define kDetailVCNib @"DetailViewController"

@implementation LocationsListViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

    //Define initial view titles and such

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"MCS Locator", @"MCS Locator");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list"];
        self.tabBarItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Our Locations", @"Our Locations");
        self.mapManager = [myMapManager sharedInstance];
        self.locations = self.mapManager.locations;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:kMainCellNib bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:kMainCellIdentifier];

    //Edit button creation, added to bar at top

    UIBarButtonItem* edit = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"EDIT"
                                                             style:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit
                                                            target:self
                                                            action:@selector(editList)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = edit;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.locations count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    myMapAnnotation* currentLocation = [self.locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CustomCellController *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kMainCellIdentifier];

    [cell configureCellWithLocation:currentLocation];

    return cell;
}

//Custom methods

- (void)editList {
    if (!self.tableView.editing) {

        //Editing mode entered

        [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"DONE"];

    } else {

        //Done editing

        [super setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"EDIT"];
    }

}




// Edit/delete method

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete == editingStyle) {
        [self.locations removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}


//Methods for the singleton and tableview data passing

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return kCellHeight;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    myMapAnnotation* currentLocation = [self.locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    DetailViewController* detailView = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:kDetailVCNib bundle:nil];
    detailView.location = currentLocation;


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];  //Push on top
}



@end
```

Then you need to do the same and make a "Custom Cell" to use (an xib file with a view of 320x65 for example) along with a class as above to define the cells.

```
#import "CustomCellController.h"


@implementation CustomCellController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

- (void)configureCellWithLocation:(myMapAnnotation*)location {
    self.title.text    = location.title;
    self.subTitle.text = location.subtitle;

}

@end
```

Comment: This is the only way to make a table view with static cells in Xcode? All I want is something that looks like: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/05/07/static-table-views-with-storyboards.html but in nibs, not storyboards

Comment: I think the Apple docs might just solve your problem: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html